# @MappedSuperclass static weaving with EclipseLink and multiple jars

Tags: jpa, orm, jpa-2.0, eclipselink, toplink

My entities objects are scattered in multiple jars.
In jar A I have a base class name MyBase which is annotated with @MappedSuperclass.
In jar B there is an entity class which derives from MyBase.
The problem is that because the weaving is done in the context of the jar file (I'm using the maven plugin) the base class (MyBase) isn't instrumented (although it should).
If I move the derived class from jar B to A then the weaving process will handle the base as well.
Since I'm working on a large project it is critical for me to develop in a modular way.
Doesn't EclipseLink support such methodology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I found to override this limitation is to add a temporary entity class to the jar where the @MappedSuperclass base class is defined and remove it after the weaving procedure.
Sad, but true ;-)

Comment: Yup, dummy entity works fine. However, I created bug report for this, you may want to vote: bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=466271

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure on the maven plugin, but you should be able to use the static weaver on both jars, you will need to call it twice to weave both, and will need both jars on the weavers classpath for both calls.

Comment: The problem is that the second jar depends on the first so I need the first one to be built before the second can be built. This means moving the weaving process out of the build process which isn't relevant for me. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can specify the jar containing your superclass as inpath - as explained [here](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/devguide/bytecode-concepts.html) and [here](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Introducing-AJDT/article.html):

> **Managing multiple projects**
>
> Building AspectJ source code requires two distinct phases; compiling
>   the source in .java and .aj files to generate .class files, and then
>   applying the aspects to the generated .class files. This second phase,
>   known as weaving, is the key difference between AspectJ and Java
>   compilers. The Java compilation process is controlled by the classpath
>   setting, which makes types available for resolution by the compiler.
>   The same classpath setting is used by the AspectJ compilation process
>   and it is configured in exactly the same way in Eclipse. However, this
>   setting is not sufficient to control both the compilation and weaving
>   steps in all situations. This is why there are two extra settings
>   available for AspectJ projects.
>
> First, there is the inpath setting. Anything specified here will be
>   made available to the weaver and so any aspects that apply will be
>   woven in. Entries can be added to a project's inpath by right-clicking
>   on the project, selecting Properties, then going to the AspectJ InPath
>   section. Entries can be either JAR files or directories (class
>   folders), such as the bin directory of another project. Anything on
>   the inpath is sent to the project's output, after potentially being
>   woven with aspects.
>
> The second additional setting is the aspectpath. Whereas the inpath
>   controls the list of things that get woven, the aspectpath controls
>   what is woven into that list. In other words, any aspects specified on
>   the aspectpath are made available to the weaving process, just as if
>   they were present in source form in the project. This setting is
>   controlled from the AspectJ Aspect Path property page and can contain
>   either JAR files or directories.
>
> An output JAR setting is also present in the AspectJ section of each
>   project's property page. This setting causes the compiler to output
>   class files directly to a JAR file, instead of to the project's output
>   folder.

Drove me crazy just like you - hope this helps. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but as I wrote on another answer the problem is that the second jar depends on the first so I need the first one to be built before the second can be built. This means moving the weaving process out of the build process which isn't relevant for me.