# eclipseLink 2.5.1 static weaving NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, tomcat, jpa, eclipselink, compile-time-weaving

I am using EclipseLink 2.5.1 on Tomcat 8. Tried to static weave jars, but got error at run time.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: mypackage.Employee._persistence_checkFetchedForSet(Ljava/lang/String;)V
        at mypackage.Employee.setAddress(Employee.java)
```

Employee extends a super class that is annotated with @MappedSuperclass. The superclass is in a
different jar. I tried to weave the jar, the superclass with @MappedSuperclass was not woven.

If I disable static weaving, dynamic weaving is not supported in Tomcat. all lazy properties will become eager fetch. Is there a way to control the fetch graph? Fetch graph is to fetch lazy properties, can not make eager properties to be lazy.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to weave the class files before packaging them into jars?

Comment: yes. weaving jar at build-time, no errors. but at run time, java.lang.NoSuchMethodError.

Comment: Probably this is a class-loading issue.

Comment: This seems to be similar/duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13392986/mappedsuperclass-static-weaving-with-eclipselink-and-multiple-jars - and the answer seems to be "not supported" by EclipseLink. (Seems that people working with JPA generally don't support modularity that much. Kinda shame.)

Comment: BTW: I created bug report for this, you may want to vote: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=466271